# To bypass inbuilt authenticator realms for java adapter in browser and mobile for testing in debug mode

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, custom-authentication

I created a custom authenticator with a custom login module for my adapter.

When I try to call my adapter in browser its showing

```
CLIENT_INTERACTION_REQUIRED{"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"lr0tsjecoeghhrf670oc8hu17v"}}}
```

I understand that webTest Security tests has crossscript relams by default in it.Is there a way to bypass this in browser? How is this realm handled in real time scenario from client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally worklight checks the uri '/my_custom_auth_request_url' for custom authenticator user name and password. This resolved my issue.